# javascript window.onbeforeunload not working correctly

Tags: javascript, onbeforeunload

**UPDATE: *there is something going on with the page I am trying to have the onbeforeunload work on. I set it up in the layout and it pops up for every page besides that one... So there has to be some broken javascript, or a javascript file that redefines onbeforeunload. Since it can only be defined once***

I am working on a Rails project and I am setting up a pop up to alert the user that their data will be lost if they leave the page without saving. So I am using window.onbeforeunload

I set it up on one page by adding this script code to the top of the view file

```
var saving = false;

window.onbeforeunload = function(){
    if(!saving)
      return 'Are you sure you don\'t want to save before you leave?';
};
```

where saving is set to true if the user hits the save button, which redirects them to a separate page.

The problem is coming up when I try to set up the EXACT same thing on a separate view file, that also needs the same functionality.

Except when I drop the code above into the file no pop up is given, at all... at any point. So then I looked around at other available options to set up the onbeforeunload function.

So I currently have it set up as:

```
var saving = false;

window.onbeforeunload = displayConfirm();

function displayConfirm(){
    if(!saving){
      if(confirm('If you leave without saving, your changes will be lost. Press cancel to go back to save')){
        confirmExit();
      }
    }
}
```

on the second page. My issue is the pop up here doesn't work the same as the first implementation. Even weirder, the pop up shows up on window load... NOT before window unload.

I have been looking around and messing around with this for a few hours now. I am starting to get really irritated since this should have been an easy addition. Seeing as how it is already set up on a separate page, and working correctly. Any insight onto what maybe going wrong, or if I am making a stupid mistake, would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

-Alan

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
window.onbeforeunload = displayConfirm;
```

You are actually calling the function right away and assigning the return value of `displayConfirm()` to window.onbeforeunload.

**Update**
But you are limited to exactly one `return` statement in your onbeforeunload-function, see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onbeforeunload). So calling "confirm" or some other custom function does not work.

Comment: Ok, Thanks. That makes more sense why it is being fired on window load. I just don't understand why one page works with the code and the other doesn't... super weird. I am testing in firefox and I have the first implementation working. It was only when I went to add it into another page that I couldn't get the same thing happening.

Comment: Unfortunately the solution you gave is giving me the same results I was getting before. Where the pop up shows up on window load and now if I press ok in the box it breaks all the javascript on the page...

Comment: Ya that was the site I originally referenced, and followed to set up the first page as it is stated in my post above. The only thing I added was that it wouldn't pop up if the user hit the save button... The thing I don't understand is why it doesn't do anything when I add the same EXACT code to the second page...

Comment: Are you sure that there is no other error occuring? Maybe check out the chrome web inspector console? Is the javascript placing the window.onbeforeunload function correctly loaded?

Comment: This is a substantially large project I got dropped on to fix all the issues. Problem is I have no line of communication with the people who originally developed it, and there are basically no comments. I guess what could be happening is some javascript code above it being broken so the code below doesn't work. Only thing is all the other javascript code works below where onbeforeunload is defined... I have been using firebug.

Comment: It's definitely something wrong with that page, because I moved that code into the layout instead of the view. Now every page (displayed through that layout) besides that one has a pop up... damn you Bucharest and your jank programming practices...

Answer (score 1):

1) `window.onbeforeunload = displayConfirm();` -- you're firing the function, instead of assigning it

2) `onbeforeunload` is great, but it's unsupported in a lot of ways. Some browsers don't even have it, period (all but the most recent Opera, for example), so if you're doing this for a wide audience, or you need it to work 100% cross-browser, `onbeforeunload` is sadly not enough on its own.

Comment: I'm pretty new to using some of these event handlers as you can tell. Could you direct me to anywhere they have a better implementation of making a more solid cross-browser compatibility

Answer (score 0):

Recently i was working on a project using this event, so i did do some search on the net.
There are few thing need to be taken into consideration when using the onbeforeunload event.

1. It is not supported by all browser. Opera, especially older version.
   Some support it partially, such as not firing when refresh button is pressed.
2. Using this event will cause the page will not be cached.

Here is an article that is more thorough about the onbeforeonload event by [Patrick Hunlock](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Mastering_The_Back_Button_With_Javascript).